# how to prevent download whole video before play video in Html video steaming?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, flowplayer

I am using flow player in my html page.
I already referred [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330501/9468362) But I Don't know What is `moov atom` ? . Where It will be added ? Is there need to install any package or module in server ? 
When the page loading, a whole video downloaded before playing . How to stop it , I want to steam a video without downloading it , as my code below it will download whole video  and then play . I need to stream that video . please how to make a video streaming . please change my direction in my code

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="flowplayer-3.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Minimal Flowplayer setup</title>
<script language="javascript">
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<a  href="http://video_URL/Edited_001.mp4" 
style="display:block;width="400px"; height="300px" id="player">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to html video streaming .

Comment: Place the `moov` atom at the beginning of the file.

Comment: where ? please give some code example @aergistal

Comment: I can't understand what you are going to tell Mr **@aergistal**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 - How to stream large .mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files)

Comment: Or another question a little more precisely about your problem with the moov atom:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946421/why-do-webkit-browsers-need-to-download-the-entire-html5-video-mp4-before-play/31340688#31340688

Comment: I referred these questions before asking ... But they can't solve my issue ... I don't have knowledge about moov atom , what is it ? where it will be added ? what you mean by beginning of file ? I thing very top line of html file ???? Please command your sample code of two or three lines

Comment: @ArunKumar the answer below the accepted one in the question quoted above has an actual command line example of how to invoke ffmpeg to achieve this.

Comment: An "atom" is part of what builds up a MP4 file format (which in turn is based on Quicktime where the term comes from). It's low-level related and if you don't want to parse the file yourself manually Foaster's link is your best bet to an easy fix. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: My mp4 files are stored in aws s3. Need to add any headers ? or where the changes will done  in mp4 video file  or html file ?